# Simple boolean data update with mongdb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, boolean, toggle, mongoid

I am using Rails and mongoid to work with mongodb.

Usually in rails when working with Active:Record, you have access to the method .toggle! which simply allows you to invert the value of a boolean field in your db.

Unfortunately this method is not available for mongoDB:

```
user = User.first
user.toggle!(:admin)
NoMethodError: undefined method `toggle!' for #<User:0x00000100eee700>
```

This is unfortunate... and stupidly enough I don't see how to get around without some complicated code...

Any suggestion on how to achieve the same result concisely ?

Thanks,

Alex

ps: also one of the problems is that when I want to modify the field, it goes through validation again... and it's asking for the :password which I don't save in the db, so:

```
User.first.admin = !User.first.admin
```

won't even work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is specifically mongoid, not mongodb. `toggle!` is a part of [ActiveRecord::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle%21), but fortunately it's not hard to replicate.

```
def toggle!(field)
  send "#{field}=", !self.send("#{field}?")
  save :validation => false
end
```

Add that into your model (or add it into a module, and include it in your model), and your Mongoid models will gain functionality equivalent to what you're used to in AR. It will read the field's value, invert it, write it (through the setter, per the `toggle!` documentation), and then save the document, bypassing validation.

Comment: This is truly awesome ! Exactly what I was looking for... :) I did not know that syntax with send ? I am not sure what it does exactly ?

Comment: `send` invokes a method to ("sends a message to") an object. `@foo.bar(:baz)` is the same as `@foo.send("bar", :baz)` - since you specify the method name with send, you can pass variables and such. This is heavily used in Ruby metaprogramming.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However after testing thoroughly it does not actually bypass all the validation. I have a validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 6, :maximum => 40, and using the toggle will through me an error on the password length... :( But not on the validates presences, etc. And it skips the attr_accesible, etc. so it's almost perfect besides the length validation

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get object's boolean field and toggle it
# @param [Object] mongoid object 
# @param [String, Symbol] flag
# @example 
#  foo = User.find('123')
#  toggle_flag!(object: foo, flag: :bar)

def toggle_flag!(object:, flag:)
  object.update(flag => !object[flag])
  object.save!
end
```

Comment: Done! I used YARD for explain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the validation did not work because of a type, the code should be:

```
save :validate => false  (not :validation)
```